# Controlling the position of list items horizontally

Tags: html, css, position, html-lists, css-position

I have a `<ul>` of items, who get bigger (with animation) on hover. Now i have made them be on the right side of the screen (using the CSS `right:0em` for the `<li>` class), and I have set the position of the `<li>` on hove to fixed so that only it will move left as it grows, and all the over objects in the  will stay to the right. The problem is that as a result of that, when I hover over it, the next item gets "under" it. How can I change that? (maybe is there a way to control only the horizontal position property of the `<li>` on hover?)

**Code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/KBprd/2/

Comment: You should provide a JSFiddle of what you have, and a clearer description of what you are trying to achieve.  I'm assuming when you hover over an LI, you want the sibling LI's to move to the right so they don't get overlapped?  Instead of using relative positioning, you can just float the LIs and they will push each other as they expand in width.

Comment: fiddle with code: http://jsfiddle.net/KBprd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code to start it is kind of hard to help. But based on what I could gather, you are wanting all the items to stay flush against the right side of the menu; only the "hovered" element is moved away from the right-side of the container.  I've slapped together an example of how to do this.  If this is not what you are looking for, provide some more code or detail in comments and we can go from there...

[Here is the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/KBprd/13/)

CSS:

```
.navigation{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:3em;
    right:0em;

}
.navigation li.slide{
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    font-weight:light;
    background:#00C9FF;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    text-align:right;
    width:53px;
    float:right;

}
.navigation li:hover,.active{
    font-size:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px!important;
    background:#5C0CE8;
}
.navigationClear {
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
     margin-bottom:-1px;  
}​
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation">
        <li data-slide="1" class="slide">Slide 1</li>
        <li class="navigationClear"></li>
        <li data-slide="2" class="slide">Slide 2</li>
        <li class="navigationClear"></li>
        <li data-slide="3" class="slide">Slide 3</li>
        <li class="navigationClear"></li>
        <li data-slide="4" class="slide">Slide 4</li>
        <li class="navigationClear"></li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: here is a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/KBprd/2/ , your solution of adding the clear <li>s doesn't seem to work. Please also do notice that the position of the <ul> has to be fixed as this is used in a parallex scrolling website

Comment: Please don't recommend bloated code like that. There are betters ways to do it then so many unnecessary `li` with the clear class

Comment: @IddoGino I have updated the code and fiddle, hope this helps!

Comment: @Andy if you are going to provide feedback such as that, you should back it up with your improved code suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @TNCodeMonkey Ok - I would recommend something cleaner, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j7EeE/

Comment: @Andy I like that.  Should have thought about specifying the width and not worrying about clearing the float(s).  Just so used to having to do that in content, to ensure that no hiccups appear.  I updated the fiddle in the post to use your fix(es), thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your hovered element hides the element below is because you have given "position:fixed" to the hovered element. I fixed your problem by giving the ul element a width so that the li elements wont line up. I also removed the fixed position of the hovered element. and then right floated the li. This way you also dont need to put "clearNavigation" after each element.

Here's your fiddle code.

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li data-slide="1">Slide 1</li>
    <li data-slide="2">Slide 2</li>
    <li data-slide="3">Slide 3</li>
    <li data-slide="4">Slide 4</li>
```

​

```
.navigation{
position:fixed;
z-index:1;
top:3em;
right:0em;
width:53px;
} 

.navigation li{
color:#000000;
display:block;
padding: 0 10px;
line-height:30px;
margin-bottom:2px;
font-weight:light;
background:#00C9FF;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
text-align:right;
width:53px;
position:relative;
right:0em;
float:right;
}

.navigation li:hover,.active{
font-size:25px;
cursor:pointer;
width:100px!important;
background:#5C0CE8;
right:0em;
}
```